# Linker error 2019 using shogun dll on windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic-linking, shogun

I'm trying to use shogun on windows. I built the library with msvc 2015 64bit. In the following there is the cmake report:

```
Could NOT find CCache (missing: CCACHE CCACHE_VERSION) 
Using system's malloc
Could NOT find GDB (missing: GDB_COMMAND GDB_VERSION) 
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "1.8.6")
dir='C:/Users/myUser/Downloads/shogun-shogun_6.1.3/shogun-shogun_6.1.3/src'
dir='C:/Users/myUser/Downloads/shogun-shogun_6.1.3/shogun-shogun_6.1.3/build/src'
Could NOT find CxaDemangle (missing: HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE) 
Could NOT find CxaDemangle (missing: HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE) 
Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing: EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "3.1.2")
Could NOT find OPENCL (missing: OPENCL_LIBRARY OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ViennaCL (missing: VIENNACL_INCLUDE_DIR VIENNACL_ENCODED_VERSION OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS OpenCL_LIBRARIES) (Required is at least version     "1.5.0")
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find TFLogger (missing: TFLogger_DIR)
A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
LAPACK requires BLAS
Could NOT find GLPK (missing: GLPK_LIBRARY GLPK_INCLUDE_DIR GLPK_PROPER_VERSION_FOUND) 
Could NOT find CPLEX (missing: CPLEX_LIBRARY CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find MOSEK (missing: MOSEK_DIR MOSEK_INCLUDE_DIR MOSEK_LIBRARY MOSEK_LIBRARIES) 
Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find JSON (missing: JSON_INCLUDE_DIR JSON_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "0.11")
Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_LIBRARY LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find LibLZMA (missing: LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIR LIBLZMA_LIBRARY LIBLZMA_HAS_AUTO_DECODER LIBLZMA_HAS_EASY_ENCODER LIBLZMA_HAS_LZMA_PRESET) 
Could NOT find SNAPPY (missing: SNAPPY_LIBRARIES SNAPPY_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Lzo includes and libraries NOT found. 
Could NOT find NLOPT (missing: NLOPT_LIBRARY NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find LPSOLVE (missing: LPSOLVE_LIBRARIES LPSOLVE_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ColPack (missing: COLPACK_LIBRARIES COLPACK_LIBRARY_DIR COLPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ARPREC (missing: ARPREC_LIBRARIES ARPREC_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Linker: Default system linker
Could NOT find Ctags (missing: CTAGS_EXECUTABLE) 
Failed to locate sphinx-build executable (missing: SPHINX_EXECUTABLE) 
Failed to locate pandoc executable (missing: PANDOC_EXECUTABLE) 
===================================================================================================================
Summary of Configuration Variables
The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * OpenMP
 * Threads

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * PythonInterp

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * CCache
 * GDB
 * Doxygen (required version >= 1.8.6)
 * CxaDemangle
 * Eigen3 (required version >= 3.1.2)
 * ViennaCL (required version >= 1.5.0)
 * rxcpp
 * TFLogger (required version >= 0.1.0)
 * BLAS
 * GLPK
 * CPLEX
 * ARPACK
 * Mosek
 * Protobuf
 * JSON (required version >= 0.11)
 * LibXml2
 * CURL
 * ZLIB
 * BZip2
 * LibLZMA
 * SNAPPY
 * LZO
 * NLopt
 * LpSolve
 * ColPack
 * ARPREC
 * Ctags
 * Sphinx
 * Pandoc

===================================================================================================================
Integrations
  OpenCV Integration is OFF      enable with -DOpenCV=ON
===================================================================================================================
Interfaces
  Python is OFF          enable with -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON
  Octave is OFF          enable with -DINTERFACE_OCTAVE=ON
  Java is OFF        enable with -DINTERFACE_JAVA=ON
  Perl is OFF        enable with -DINTERFACE_PERL=ON
  Ruby is OFF        enable with -DINTERFACE_RUBY=ON
  C# is OFF              enable with -DINTERFACE_CSHARP=ON
  R is OFF           enable with -DINTERFACE_R=ON
  Lua is OFF         enable with -DINTERFACE_LUA=ON
  Scala is OFF       enable with -DINTERFACE_SCALA=ON
===================================================================================================================
To compile shogun type
  make

To install shogun to C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun type
  make install

or to install to a custom directory
  make install DESTDIR=/my/special/path
  (or rerun cmake with -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/my/special/path) to just change the prefix
===================================================================================================================
Configuring done
Generating done
```

The library build successfully but when I try to build the following example code:

```
#include <shogun/base/init.h>

using namespace shogun;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    init_shogun_with_defaults();
    exit_shogun();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls'     version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:..\build_release\shoguntest.exe     @C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\shoguntest.exe.14740.610.jom
shogun.lib(Time.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_timeGetTime referenced in function "public: __cdecl shogun::CTime::CTime(bool)"     (??0CTime@shogun@@QEAA@_N@Z)
..\build_release\shoguntest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I don't understand where is the problem. The library built succesfully without any error.

Comment: link to ``winmm.lib`` cause the linker is unable to find ``timeGetTime`` API: ``#pragma comment(lib, "winmm")``

Comment: Adding the #pragma solved the problem in Release build. However, I'm getting a lot of LNK2038 linker error in Debug build.

Comment: You will need to link to debug versions of shotgun dlls and libraries. It's probably referring to release versions

Comment: In Debug build I get a lot of LNK2038 error on obj:

`shogun.lib(DifferentiableFunction.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
    shogun.lib(DifferentiableFunction.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj`

Is it a problem with the debug version of the shogun library?

Comment: My guess was correct. The shotgun libraries that you are referring to is for release versions. You should build/download debug version of the corresponding libraries.

Comment: With the shogun release build everything works (with #pragma). With the shogun debug built with msvc 2015. Building the example in debug mode I get the LNK2038 error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a pretty simple problem: You need to link with 
`winmm.lib`, see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629(v=vs.85).aspx